# how to use file content as variable but keep the `\0`

Tags: bash

I have a file content separated by "\0" for example: `find ./ -type f -print0 > myfile.txt`
Then I want to read the file content into a variable but still keep the "\0". `"$(< myfile.txt)"` does not work in this case, all the "\0" are striped.

Comment: Bash uses C strings for regular variables. C strings are NUL terminated. Thus, they can't possibly store NUL literals within their contents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Targeting Bash

Use an array, not a regular (NUL-delimited) string.

With support for bash 3.x (and 4.0-4.3):

```
files=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  files+=( "$file" )
done < <(find . -type f -print0)
```

...or, with 4.4 or later:

```
readarray -d '' files < <(find . -type f -print0)
```

Either way, you can then regenerate the original stream with:

```
printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}"
```

---

#### Targeting POSIX sh (+ coreutils)

If by contrast you need to support a non-bash shell that doesn't support arrays, you end up needing to use base64-encoding, uuencoding, or another formulation that encodes content such that literal NULs can no longer take place.

Thus, assuming GNU coreutils `base64`:

```
files_b64=$(find . -type f -print0 | base64 -w 0 -)
```

...and, later, to decode to the original stream:

```
printf '%s\n' "$files_b64" | base64 -d -
```

If coreutils isn't sufficiently portable, the `openssl` command line tool offers similar facilities; adjustments to use them are left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Sheeze Charles, knocked that one out of the park!

Comment: Insightful. Using `openssl`  would be `find . -type f -print0 | openssl enc -base64`

Comment: Very inconvenient! But I think store them differently then replay the stream afterwards is the only way to go then.

Comment: Of course, the need to replay is only pertinent if you actually need the original NUL-delimited format back out. For many cases, a bash array is useful as-is; `for file in "${files[@]}"` lets you iterate over the array directly as-captured, f/e. Process substitution is also handy, to be able to generate a file-like object from which your reconstructed stream can be read.